# cannot quote my message on slack app for windows with >>>

Tags: slack

Trying to quote my message text in slack app for windows. But it seemed not to work. This is what I'm writing: This is my text and this is the >>>multiple line text I want to quote.

But it's not formatted as quote or anything. It just displays: This is my text and this is the >>>multiple line text I want to quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for you to be able to quote, you need to start the line with '>>>'

thats the same for mac too !!!

try doing this:

```
This is my text and this is the 
>>>multiple line text I want to quote
```

and it should work fine
!

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks for mentioning to start the line with! Now it works.